# How to get SQLCMD headers and data with -y flag

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I have a query I'm running on my SQL Server database via `SQLCMD`. In order to get long text fields without any data limit, I'm using the `-y0` flag.

Unfortunately, when using the `-y0` flag, my query headers disappear, and the query returns only the data. I want to receive the headers from the query as well.

Given that the query is `select * from sales;`, I thought about doing something like this:

```
sqlcmd -Q "select top 0 * from (select * from sales) as _; select * from sales;" -y0 -S "127.0.0.1,1433" -o output_file.csv
```

In order to run one query for the headers and another for the data, but the -y0 flag affects the first query as

I would like to find a solution involving only one execution of sqlcmd.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The typical method for what you're doing in the first query is to make the WHERE clause always false:

```
WHERE 1 = 0
```

But I don't know if that will affect `-y0` at all.

If you do two executions, you can do something like this:

```
sqlcmd -Q "select * from sales where 1 = 0;" -S "127.0.0.1,1433" -o output_file_hdr.csv
sqlcmd -Q "select * from sales;" -y0 -S "127.0.0.1,1433" -o output_file_data.csv
copy /A output_file_hdr.csv + output_file_data.csv output_file.csv
del output_file_hdr.csv
del output_file_data.csv
```

Personally, though, I would probably use PowerShell's `Invoke-Sqlcmd` if `sqlcmd.exe` is misbehaving:

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -Server '127.0.0.1' -Database $Database -MaxCharLength ([int32]::MaxValue) `
    -Query "select * from sales;" | `
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path output_file.csv;
```